# Printing emails including the attached PDF documents in Gmail

Tags: gmail, pdf, printing, gmail-attachments

I am desperately looking for a solution how to print from Gmail (webinterface, no email client as Thunderbird etc) an email together with the PDF attachments into a single PDF document meaning I do not want to print both separately and then combine them to one PDF. I tried  already different ways but could not find any solution. I have Internet Explorer, Chrome and Adobe Acrobat Pro. Would be great if anyone knows a solution.

Comment: I don't think that's possible with the current Gmail web interface.

Comment: Ok. That's what i supposed :-(.